# Not getting value in $_SERVER from SetEnv variable in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, cpanel, mod-env

I have set some variables in .htaccess file with **SetEnv** but it's not getting by php file using **$_SERVER**.

Here is the code of htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

# Enviroment variables; change these to match server configurations
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT development
SetEnv APP_DB_HOSTNAME localhost
SetEnv APP_DB_USERNAME root
SetEnv APP_DB_PASSWORD root
SetEnv APP_DB_NAME root_pro
SetEnv APP_ENC_KEY xxxxx-xxx-xxx
```

But I didn't got the value in **$_SERVER['ENVIRONMENT']**. Please give advice on it please.

**Note**: This is not working in my live server and there is already **mod_env** already enabled.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: make sure that `AllowOverride` is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `AllowOverride` is set to FileInfo (or All):

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

inside the relevant directory.

Also it might be possible that the environment variables were removed by suexec.

Comment: How can I do check or change using cPanel or whm login ?

Comment: Yes, there is AllowOverride is All. But still have same issue.